# Initialize a new CDKTF for Terraform application in Python

Tags: python, pip, terraform, cdktf

I am unable to initialize a terraform application using CDKTF and Python. I have created a virtual env and initializing it.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cdktf-build-python?in=terraform/cdktf

Using
`cdktf init --template="python-pip" --local` throws an Error:
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Unable to find "pip".

I have added `c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip` and `c:\python37\Scripts` to Path as well

Comment: Can you provide error messages and code, as actual text, not image. You can provide screenshot as a supplementary data if you want.

Comment: Ok. I have changed it

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/issues/267

Comment: What cdktf version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using `cdktf init --template="python-pip" --local` should work, if not it's a bug that needs to be solved.